# Inverse function of R Pracma whittaker smoothing?

Tags: r, math, smoothing

I am using Pracma's whittaker function [here](https://github.com/cran/pracma/blob/master/R/whittaker.R)

```
whittaker <- function(y, lambda = 1600, d = 2){
    #   Smoothing with a finite difference penalty
    #   y:      signal to be smoothed
    #   lambda: smoothing parameter (rough 50..1e4 smooth)
    #   d:      order of differences in penalty (generally 2)

    m <- length(y)
    E <- eye(m)
    D <- diff(E, lag = 1, differences = d)
    B <- E + (lambda * t(D) %*% D)
    z <- solve(B, y)

    return(z)
}
```

for which I need to find the inverse function of whittaker smoothing, 
 does there exist any inverse whittaker smoothing algorithm? Even approximation could be useful.

*Preliminary attempth*

```
y = B*z            //solve(B,z)
z = B^{-1} y       // *B
y = B*z
```

so I have to find out `B` that is

```
E <- eye(length(y))
D <- diff(E, lag = 1 , differences 2)
B <- E + (lambda * t(D) %*% D)
```

so

```
y<- B * z
```

which I understand so that the smoothing is lossless (no information getting lost in the transformation) so the inverse should contain the same information as the initial data.

---

As demonstrated, it does not seem to be impossible to create the inverse function of Whittaker smoothing but I would expect such a function to exist already in R.

**Does there exist inverse function of whittaker smoothing in R?**

Comment: Whittaker smoothing is *not* a function, it returns a set of points / a time series. To make it a function would require linear or, e.g., spline interpolation. And -- obviously -- the original data points cannot be recovered from the smoothed points (smoothing always involves loss).

Comment: @HansW. does there exist any approximate inverse function of whittaker smoothing? If you have a noise signal, it is often far easier to predict its whittaker-smoothed version but then I would like to get the original signal back or some approximate values about it?

Comment: No. Think of linear regression: Quite different sets of data points will generate the same regression line; the same here. I guess you should reconsider what problem you really want to solve -- or the description of the task you want to solve is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you were absolutely right and there is an inverse to Whittaker smoothing (except maybe at the end points). It is indeed quite easy to revert the smoothing procedure, assuming parameters `lambda` and `d` are the same -- and you were on the right track.

```
library(pracma)
inv_whittaker <- function(z, lambda = 1600, d = 2) {
    m = length(z); E = eye(m)
    D = diff(E, lag = 1, differences = d)
    B = E + (lambda * t(D) %*% D)
    y = B %*% z
    return(y)
}
```

Let's apply this to the example on the help page, starting with a 'jitted' sine function.

```
xx = linspace(0, 10*pi, 1000)
t1 = sin(xx) + rnorm(1000)/10
t3 = whittaker(t1, lambda = 1600)
```

Now we try to get `t1` back from `t3`.

```
t2 = inv_whittaker(t3, lambda = 1600)
max(abs(t1-t2))
## [1] 3.527845e-12
```

I found this quite surprising and I am not really sure it works that good for all corner cases and end points, like when you take for `t1` the exact sine curve.